# ReportViewer and accessibility

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a ReportViewer in a Winforms application that has to be 100% accessible.

I can find no way of using the toolstrip with the keyboard only. I can tab into the toolstrip and then arrow through the first couple of buttons to the text box, where I get stuck. The arrow keys do not take me out of the text box, and the tab key takes me to the zoom combo and the Find text box. I simply cannot get to any of the buttons on the toolstrip other than the first two navigation buttons.

Any ideas how to resolve this (C#)?

Comment: You should create [`AccessibleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.accessibleobject(v=vs.110).aspx) instances where you can set up things such as keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @JNYRanger Can't really follow that. If I create an AccessibileObject instance of the ReportViewer, surely I still have the problem that I cannot set hotkeys for the items of the toolstrip individually.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you need sort the `Tab Order`.
and for arrow buttons you can write events. for Report viewer key down or key press.
simply write these codes for example arrow Right:

in key press event:

```
if (e.KeyData==Keys.Right)
            {
                //do something
            }
```

if you want Report Viewer without tab Stop, in Report viewer properties set `TabStop = false`